# Decode RSS characters (WP8.1/AppStudio)

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, rss, windows-phone-8.1

I've made a simple RSS Reader using AppStudio for Windows. The problem is my RSS Feed xml contains some characters that need to be decoded in order to be properly fetched by my application.

To be more specific, the character which should be shown as "ë" is being shown as "& # x e b ;"(notice spaces between characters so the browser does not auto-decode it.)

I've tried making changes into the Html2Xaml.cs file, but without any success.

If any of you could guide me to solving this problem I would be really grateful. Just put me in the right track and I'll be sure to find a solution, if you do not have a specific answer that is.

Here is the full Html2Xaml file uploaded on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/EgT3wxTm

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of app you need to use:

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or HtmlEncode

or

System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode or HtmlEncode

there are more methods in this class, like Url encoding and decoding.

Comment: I am using HtmlAgilityPack ,and normally it should automatically convert those characters to "ë", but it doesnt. Take a look at the code, you can see at the function "private static string PreprocessEntities(string html)" where it converts these entities to how they should be ({"&euml;", "&#x00EB;"}).

Thanks in advance.